# Recent users query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join, linq-to-objects

I have 2 tables, for example let's assume that this is the data:

users table:

```
 ------------------------------
|   user_id     |   username    |
 ------------------------------
| 1             | danny         |
| 2             | george        |
| 3             | lana          |
| 4             | kim           |
| 5             | tim           |
 ------------------------------
```

users_logins table:

```
     -----------------------------------------------
    | record_id | user_id   |   recorder            |
     -----------------------------------------------
    | 1         | 3         | 2012-11-06 04:18:26   |
    | 2         | 3         | 2012-11-06 04:31:05   |
    | 3         | 2         | 2012-11-06 03:44:22   |
    | 4         | 1         | 2012-11-06 04:18:58   |
    | 5         | 1         | 2012-11-06 04:30:15   |
    | 6         | 3         | 2012-11-06 04:31:05   |   X
    | 7         | 1         | 2012-11-06 05:53:47   |
    | 8         | 1         | 2012-11-06 05:55:15   |   X
    | 9         | 4         | 2012-11-06 05:59:31   |
    | 10        | 4         | 2012-11-06 06:12:55   |   X
     -----------------------------------------------
```

I want to show 3 recent logged in users, so the result will show only the rows that marked with X right to them, or in words unique recent logins.

How would the query look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
var resentLogedInUsers =
    users
        .Join(
            users_logins,
            u => u.user_id,
            l => l.user_id,
            (u, l) => new
                            {
                                User = u,
                                Login = l.recorder
                            })
        .GroupBy(j => j.User)
        .Select(l => new {User = l.Key, LastLogin = l.Max(d => d.Login)})
        .OrderByDescending(r => r.LastLogin)
        .Take(3);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this for linq to objects

```
 (from login in users_logins.OrderByDescending(user => user.recorder) 
 from user in users
 where user.user_id == login.user_id
 select user).Distinct().Take(3)
```

This query
1. first sorts on date
2. then joins sorted login data with user data,
3. then take distinct users
4. and then finally take first 3 records.

---

Following is alternative query

```
from login in users_logins.OrderByDescending(user =>user.recorder).GroupBy(user=>user.recorder).SelectMany( users=>users.First()).Take(3) 
from user in users
where user.user_id == login.user_id
select user
```

This query
1. first sorts
2. then groups on user_id
3. then take first 3 records with different user id,
4. then joins with users data.